# Groupby Pandas dataframe and drop values conditionally based on rank

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3
 a   |   8  |  9
 a   |   3  |  7
 a   |   1  |  3
 a   |   0  |  8
 b   |   6  |  18
 b   |   2  |  6
```

I would like to drop everything but the 2nd and 3rd top value for Col2, by grouping Col1, assuming it's possible

Output desired:

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3
 a   |   3  |  7
 a   |   1  |  3
 b   |   2  |  6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible by using `cumcount`

```
df[df.groupby('Col1').cumcount().isin([1,2])]
Out[423]: 
  Col1  Col2  Col3
1    a     2     7
2    a     1     3
5    b     2     6
```

More information :

```
df.groupby('Col1').cumcount()
Out[435]: 
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    0
5    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: those were example numbers, not meant to be representative. But it could work if i can create a sequential column based on Col1!

Comment: see edit. the 2nd and 3rd value wont always have values 1 and 2

Comment: @NBC man , you really miss understood , my solution , that 1, 2 is from cumcount not your dataframe